# Alternative file format to ESRI Shapefile?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, shapefile, format

ESRI Shapefile requires multiple file, such as .shp, .prj and etc.
 and it's not preferable for me.
So I'm looking for substitute to it.

Are there good file formats which meet the follows ?

- Results in a single file
- Can be loaded by both of QGIS and ArcGIS without any conversions
- Keep the same kind of information as the ESRI Shapefile
  (eg. Don't lose info on projection)
- Don't seem to be deprecated soon
- Don't get larger size than ESRI Shapefile

Comment: @user30184 that's not relevant. The *question* is still a duplicate.  Answers can (and should) be added to the [original Q.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18159/alternatives-to-shapefiles-as-open-source-cross-platform-dataset-types).